# nvd3 js - Refresh a "chart" data but keep filtered values

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

When I filter some data in my nvd3 pieChart (using the built-in filter in the pieChart legend) and refresh/update my pieChart data, my previous filter is reset.

I want to update the pieChart data, but I want to keep my filtered values.

To update my pieChart data, I'm doing:

```
    function updateData3() {
        $.getJSON('/wso2-ui/dashboard3Servlet', function(data) {
            console.log(data)

            d3.select("#chart3")
            .datum(data)
            .transition().duration(1200)
            .call(chart3);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart3.update);

            return chart3;
        });
    }
```

Here is an example:

In image 1, I have my pieChart populated with data from a JSON.

In image 2, I uncheck the "option Four" in the pieChart legend, and then my pieChart is updated properly.

In image 3, as I'm doing a pieChart update with the code above, my pieChart legend is also updated (i.e. the option "Four" is checked again, automatically). This is what I don't want to happen.

How can I update the pieChart with updated JSON *without losing the filters* applied via the pieChart legend ("One", "Two"...)?

[image]

Comment: What is the question? What is the specific problem?

Comment: @il_raffa, question updated.

Comment: I edited your question a bit, hoping to highlight and focus even more on what the question is.